# How does the Grand Prix Attack compare to the Rossolimo/Canal Attack?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense

How does the Grand Prix Attack compare to the Rossolimo/Canal Variations for someone who wants to develop an anti-Sicilian repertoire? What are the pros and cons of each opening? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost it should be noted that while you can employ the Grand Prix Attack against basically any Sicilian, the Rossolimo/Canal Variations can only  be played against 2...Nc6 and 2...d6 Sicilians.

If you look at GM games, the Rossolimo will appear more than the Grand Prix Attack due to being more solid (not moving the f pawn so early and following classical opening principles) and retaining white's opening advantage. Opening theory has found that black can equalize in some lines against the Grand Prix Attack. However, for people way below GM level, the Grand Prix Attack is a great weapon which can often lead to devastating attacks against the black king and interesting dynamic positions. Although the Rossolimo can also result in attacks against the black king, it is more commonly associated to positional games in which white will play against black's doubled c pawns while conceding the bishop pair.

If I had to summarize the advantages/disadvantages of both openings in some bullet points, it would go as follows:

Rossolimo/Canal Variations:

- Often lead to slower and more positional games
- Harder to play for white and black (some positional ideas are hard to understand for both sides)
- More lines to learn for you and your opponent, and so, the better prepared player will often hold some advantage (some lines white plays d4 straight away, some lines you prepare with c3, some lines you play d3...)
- As you climb the elo ladder, this opening can still consistently be used as your main weapon against d6/classical Sicilians
- Great if you play the Ruy Lopez and to a lesser extent the Nimzo-Indian, since you can borrow ideas from them in some lines

Grand Prix Attack:

- Often lead to more aggressive double-edged positions
- Opening moves stay more or less the same regardless of what your opponent plays (easier to play)
- Very thematic ideas and pawn breaks (easier to play)
- Loses a little of its effectiveness as you climb the elo ladder
- Can be played against pretty much any Sicilian

Comment: Great Summary!  Years ago as white I would play 1.f4 c5 2. e4  I liked the simplicity of the grand prix.  But every Sicilian player was well prepared for it.